# User is a member of a group, user group list does not include group

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Current behavior: What's happening is we are caching all of the group's and group members using the google directory api. We find that this specific user is in group that we want to remove him/her from. We do an api call to remove the user and we get a  URL not found response.

Desired behavior: Remove xuser@xappsite from the xgroup@xappsite group.

Currently if you look in the console you can see that the xuseraccount user lookup does not contain the xgroup group, but if you look in the group lookup section you will see that xuseris apart of the xgroup group.

We then attempt to do a directory.group.member.delete command with the URI:

Here's the send request.

> [FINE]2015-04-14 15:36:58
>   [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection]:
>   sun.net.www.MessageHeader@6afa3ce57 pairs: {DELETE
>   /admin/directory/v1/groups/xgroup@xappsite/members/xuser%40xappsite
>   HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: Application/JSON}{Content-Type:
>   Application/JSON} -- removed extra response

Here's the response

> [FINE]2015-04-14 15:36:58
>   [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection]:
>   sun.net.www.MessageHeader@2cdf88d214 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 404 Not
>   Found}{Vary: X-Origin}{Content-Type: application/json;
>   charset=UTF-8}{Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2015 19:36:59 GMT}{Expires: Tue, 14
>   Apr 2015 19:36:59 GMT}{Cache-Control: private,
>   max-age=0}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{X-Frame-Options:
>   SAMEORIGIN}{X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block}{Server:
>   GSE}{Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.5}{Accept-Ranges: none}{Vary:
>   Origin,Accept-Encoding}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}

TLDR:

Basically this user is a member of a group according to the groups application inside of google, but the user is not a member of the group according to the user group listing.

Is this a bug inside of google? I tried submitting a support request with them but it didn't' go very far. The solution we found was to manually remove and re-add users to each group. It also seems like this only happens with owners and managers of groups.

Comment: In groups.list(https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list) , if you add userkey(userKey query parameter returns all groups for which a user or group has a membership), are you able to see the missed group (in users.list) for the above user? please let me know

Comment: I did the request (Oauthed with the google apps customer in question, put in the userkey section the user I am referring to).

I am not able to see the missed group in this list (It's actually the same api call that I'm doing, but I double checked just in case).

I also double checked and inside of google this user is a member of the group if you go to the groups app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're pretty sure the answer to this question was that the user we were looking for had an Alias or a google ID listed as the member of the group, so when we were doing the DELETE with the primary email address the user would not get removed from the group. We haven't seen this come up again, but another fix is remove the person from the group you are trying to remove them from by hand in the portal.